# (Shell) Create a recursive function which return the basename of files, preserving hirarchy

Tags: bash, shell, recursion, symlink, basename

Currently, I have the following:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

pathlink() {
  for file in "$@";
  do
    if [ -d "$file" ];
    then
#      echo "$file"
      pathlink "$file/*"
    else
      echo '/home/buddhilw/dotfiles/'$(basename $file)
#       ln -nfs /home/buddhilw/dotfiles/$(basename $directory) $directory
    fi
  done
}

pathlink \
  /home/buddhilw/.config/* \
  /home/buddhilw/.local/* \
  /home/buddhilw/.bashrc
```

I get the following error, for every file in upper-directories,

```sh
basename: extra operand ‘/home/buddhilw/.local/quicklisp/dists’
```

Comment: Btw.: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: change `pathlink "$file/*"`  to  `pathlink $file/*`

Comment: @YuriGinsburg: This would get you in trouble, if `file` contains spaces. I would do a `pathlink "$file"/*`.

Comment: @BuddhiLW : I changed your tag _bash_ into _shell_, because there is nothing in your question related to bash. May I suggest that you also update the question's title accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

change `basename $file` to `basename "${file}"`. It likely just ran into a filename with a space in it.

i would suspect you'd have an easier time leaving this kinda stuff up to the `find` utility.

```
find /some/path -printf '%d %y %Y %f\n'
```

provides all the info you need as far as i can see. the first column indicating the depth, the 2nd and 3rd indicating the filetype (like d for directories; one follows symlinks one does not), and the 4th column being the file's basename.

you can put that command in a `bash` script, change the `\n` to `\0`, pipe it into a while loop with `IFS=" " read -r -d$'' DEPTH TYPEA TYPEB FILENAME` and you have a very well rounded filescanner.

Comment: The braces don't add any value here; `basename "$file"` is quite sufficient and idiomatic.

Comment: never a downside really, i always brace them all :)

Comment: It is not sufficient to quote the argument of `basename`. It is necessary to quote the sub-shell expression as well: `"$(basename "$file")"`.